# Script de javascript que no se ejecuta en PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

tras estar probando varias soluciones me es imposible ejecutar de forma correcta un script de javascript dentro de php.
Contexto:
Me gustaría hacer que cuando un usuario complete mi formulario se le guarde en el localstorage un value (su nombre), entonces a través de una función de php le asigno a una variable de php, un script de javascript y dentro de ese script de javascript, le inserto el valor del $_POST del nombre del usuario a través de php.
Resultados:

1. Me sale el valor de null (en caso de ponerlo con comillas dobles)
2. Se asigna literalmente el valor de $name;
   Codes:
   Javascript (index page):

   ```
    <script>

    var detected = localStorage.getItem('such');
    console.log(detected);
    if (detected <= 0){
        console.log('nothing to do here');
    }
    else{
        console.log('jisus'); 
    document.getElementById("supra_grrr").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector('.grrr .value').innerHTML = detected;
   ```

   $(".grrr .value").html(detected);

   }

   ```
    </script>
   ```

Php + Javascript code (Send page):

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
            if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['gilipollas']['tmp_name'])){
   $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
 $detected_issue = '<script type="text/javascript">
    var sus = <?=$nombre?> ;
    
    if (sus <=0){
        console.log("eeee");
    }
    else{
        localStorage.setItem("such",sus);
        console.log("yesnt");
    }
    </script>
    ';
    echo $detected_issue;
```

Comment: JS se ejecuta en el cliente, PHP en el servidor por lo cual necesitaras hacerlo con AJAX, hacer peticiones al servidor y validarlo, de la forma que lo estas haciendo nunca te va funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Es más elegante hacerlo con ajax, pero para este caso, el string está mal construído.

```
    $detected_issue = '<script type="text/javascript">
    var sus = '.$nombre.' ;
    
    if (sus <=0){
        console.log("eeee");
    }
    else{
        localStorage.setItem("such",sus);
        console.log("yesnt");
    }
    </script>
    ';
    echo $detected_issue;
```